# Why does the condition in mentioned code blocks succeeds as true?

Tags: java

Below is a Java code that should evaluate to false as ***b=false*** evaluates to '*false*' and b is assigned value *false*. second part of *OR* condition is ***b==true*** which is also false as ***b*** is ***false***. But when I test run this code in *Dr. Java Editor*  I am getting output as ***check true***

```
boolean b=true; 
if(b=false || b==true)
 System.out.println("check true");
```

Comment: It probably means `b = (false || (b == true))`.

Comment: +1 above comment is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `(b = false || b == true)` does not evaluate like `(b = false) || (b == true)`,
but like `b = (false || (b == true))`, which is true if b is true.

The critical point is the operator precedence, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
boolean b=true;
if(b=false || b==true)
```

Now this is equivalent to

```
 if(b= b == true)
```

we can simplify this to

```
if(b=b)
```

Now `b=b` is `true`

Comment: nonsense you cannot do true=false. you cannot assign false to true

Comment: you edited too many times, don't know what you are trying to say